# What is the best way to transfer a large report over the wire?

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, report

I currently have a client server program.  The client will request a report from the server, the server will in turn query the database.  I need to be able to send the entire report to the client without running into memory issues.  I was thinking of sending it in chunks but that would cause a bunch of performance issues becasue we would have to repeat the same query over and over until the entire report has been sent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say for sure without more information, but it sounds like the [continuous scrolling pattern](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/ContinuousScrolling) might work well for you.

Here's an example:
http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=371